# How to pass bindingResult object to an another request URI in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In PRINT_LOGIN request URI am binding errors to bindingResult object and I need to pass that to another request URI (VERIFY_ACCOUNT) there I can check the errors and do my stuff

```
@RequestMapping(PRINT_LOGIN)
public String printLogin(Map<String, Object> model, @Valid PrintLoginForm printLoginForm, 
    BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String accountNum = printLoginForm.getAccountNumber();
    String zipCode = printLoginForm.getZipCode();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(accountNum) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(zipCode)) {
        // valid
    } else { // Invalid
        bindingResult.reject("ERROR_INVALID_ACCOUNTNUMBER");
        // How to pass this bindingResult to the below URI ? 
        return createRedirectUri(VERIFY_ACCOUNT);
    }
    return VIEW_ACCOUNT_INDENTIFICATION;
}

@RequestMapping(VERIFY_ACCOUNT)
public String verifyAccount(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //How to get bindingResult object from the above request ? 
    return VIEW_VERIFY_ACCOUNT;
}
```

Comment: You don't. Why should it. Also I don't really get your logic, you are validating the form and still again manually validate the model? Basically you are doing the same thing twice...

Comment: Actually inside this if condition another type of validation service will be called if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(accountNum) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(zipCode)) {
        // validation service will validate the inputted values. then valid or invalid will be updated to binding results. Now this binding results should be passed to redirected request (VERIFY_ACCOUNT)
    }

Comment: You don't pass the binding result. But still your validation logic is weird and imho duplicated. You should specify the view to render from the method you do the validation. You can try hacking it into flash attributes but still generally that isn't something you should be using it for.

Comment: I have common logic in printLogin method, but different requests will come and access it. in that case I should render my model in requested method view rite. for ex: If req1 comes and error happened - same method view render & If req2 comes and error happened - diff method view should render, So for this I should pass what error happened rite ?

Comment: The logic for determine the view should be in a single method. You don't pass the results to another method through a request, if you need that imho your design is flawed. You should render error messages based the information in the model , you don't need separate methods for that.

Comment: okay then I will write two method's to get it solve. thanks.